# Attention, focus, and respect as distributable resources

Tags: etymology, language-evolution

I'm curious about why we say things like, "If I could have your attention please", "Please give me your focus", and "Please give me the same respect you want for yourself". When did these become distributable resources?

Does anyone have insight into how this came about and **why we use these as we do**?
We don't use other intangible nouns like this, so why do we use a select few in this special way? ("Could I have your kindness?" sounds weird, as do things like, *good humor*, and *excitement*".)

Comment: "Can I have your mercy?" or "Give us mercy" would be another usage. _Grace_, _love_, _a chance_ are a few others. Negative requests are also common: "Don't give me that attitude."

Comment: How about "Friends, Romans, countrymen: lend me your ears"?

Answer (score 1):

As nouns, *attention* and *respect* have always been exchangeable commodities -- one *pays respect to* or *pays attention to* a person or object worthy of such payment, and we seem always to have done so. (In French, one *does* attention*, but I have never run across that usage in English except when I was teaching ESL.) People have also always asked for or demanded attention and respect. It's the standard usage.

That use of *focus*, on the other hand, is definitely non-standard. I have never heard or seen it until you posted this question -- the usual use is to ask that the listener focus, or "focus on me", "focus on what we're doing", etc.

*The phrase is *faire attention*, and the verb *faire* is used in the sense of *to do* rather than *to make*.

Comment: I'm more interested in *why* they're standard usage.

Comment: @Nathan: you *do* realise that that is never and has never been more than guesswork, right? All we have is the record of usage to work with, and analogous uses in other languages. The working analogy in English is to accord *respect*, *attention*, *admiration* and so forth an equal footing with *tribute* (which is now metaphorical, but which was once money or goods).

Comment: I do realize this. I was just curious if anyone had some special knowledge or a good theory. I've been surprised here before. As for focus, that's a common usage in my classroom environment ("If I could have your focus for another minute, we can finish this lesson.")

Comment: Is it a computer related class? Stealing, grabbing, and having focus are computing terms of art. As a side note: one might ask when "affection" became wet ("showering him with affection")

Comment: @horatio No, this is not a computer class. Just junior high.